# Is there any simple way to print (literally to a printer) the contents from more than one view in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For instance I have a view which displays a list of all the songs I have for a particular set. Is there any solution in rails where you can print the view for each song that is contained within the set? Just so I can save the user having to visit every single song page on the set list. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a rails specific issue, you can do this with javascript.

Basically, what you need to do is have a javascript click event with your print button that loads the other song pages into the current page (with AJAX) but have the contents be hidden on the `screen` CSS media type, but not hidden on the `print` media type.

```
@media print {
  #OtherSongs { display: block }
}
@media screen {
  #OtherSongs { display: none }
}
```

Once everything is set up properly, call `print()` javascript command.

An alternative to dynamically loading the other song content with AJAX would be to have it there at page load (again hidden in `screen` media type).  This is probably easier to code, but may make the page slower to load initially.